set and get cookie in a webserver by Delphi
I created a stand alone webserver by Delphi. These objects are on my form: webmodule1, HTTPSoapDispatcher1, HTTPSoapDispatcher1, WSDLHTMLPublish1.
my procedures are:
procedure Tservice1.write_cookie; stdcall;
var mc:tstringlist;
begin
mc:=tstringlist.Create;
mc.Add('name=1234');
GetSOAPWebModule.Response.SetCookieField(mc,'plansoft.local:5173','/',now+1000,false);
end;

procedure Tservice1.read_cookie; stdcall;
var s:string;
begin
s:=GetSOAPWebModule.Request.Cookie;
form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;

When I call write_cookie procedure, no cookie is created. and obviously after call read_cookie procedure, no cookie is read. Can you help me and tell me what I must do?

Hi! Step into SetCookieField and look what is happening there first thing. I bet you'll find good hints.
